# Nest elasticsearch sort by enum values specific order

Tags: elasticsearch

product model in elasticSearch is like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ProductStatus ProductStatus { get; set; }
}
```

and ProductStatus enum specify Status of product

```
public enum ProductStatus
{
    Available = 1,
    UnAvailable = 2,
    CommingSoon = 3,
    OutOfOrder = 4
}
```

i want sort product search result based on this order: Available, CommingSoon, UnAvailable and OutOfOrder, and may this order change later,
how this sort possible in elasticSearch, and NEST

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do function score to boost for each of the variable then do sum on function scores

```
function_score": {
    "query": {},
    "boost": "boost for the whole query",
    "functions": [
        {
            "filter": {},
            "FUNCTION": {}, 
            "weight": number
        },
        {
            "FUNCTION": {} 
        },
        {
            "filter": {},
            "weight": number
        }
    ],
    "max_boost": number,
    "score_mode": "(multiply|max|...)",
    "boost_mode": "(multiply|replace|...)",
    "min_score" : number
}
```